# Connect Diferent brand PLC

Tags: powerline-networking

I have actually 2 PLCs os TP-LInk Serie 600 TL-PA6030KIT connected from the Router to one machine, and now someone gift to me a Devolo dLAN 650+ PLC, but its only one.

is possible to connect this new PLC to the PLC in the router and get working the other TPLink connected to the other PC, and get working the 3 at the same time?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of the devices you have mentioned use the `HomePlug` standard. As such, they should be compatible with each other.

**TP Link:**

http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/cat-18_TL-PA6030KIT.html

> **HomePlug** AV standard compliant, high-speed data transfer rates of up
>   to 600Mbps

**Devolo**

http://www.devolo.com/en/Products/dLAN-650+/

> Standards IEEE 802.3, IEEE 802.3u, IEEE 802.3ab, IEEE 802.3x, IEEE
>   802.1p, IEEE 1901 Auto MDI/X **HomePlug**

**Statement from Devolo:**

> All adapters that are certified to the HomePlug standard are
>   compatible and work together. To connect devolo adapters to HomePlug
>   adapters from different manufacturers to form a common network, assign
>   all of the devices the same password.

Comment: After you works I open the package, and try to set the new PLC, first time the new PLC connect to one of the TP-link, but the other TP-link get out of the network, the second time the Devolo dont sync, but at the first time I get the 3 PLCs working, thanks!

Comment: @Zenth There can be oddities, especially when using the encryption. Glad you got it working.